# Can I achieve same regex results using less characters. Seeking contains substring regex

Tags: regex

I'm using Google sheets query function which contains a regex command "MATCHES".

I need to sum Col1 if Col2 contains either of the string dog, cat or fish.

This is my ugly solution and I wonder if there's a neater way:

```
(.*)?dog(.*)?|(.*)?cat(.*)?|(.*)?fish(.*)?
```

In English, evaluate to true if the cell in question contains or equals any of these 3 strings. There may or may not be text on either side.

cat|dog|fish does not work in this environment. From their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

> matches - A (preg) regular expression match. haystack matches needle
>   is true if the regular expression in needle matches haystack.
>   Examples: where country matches '.*ia' matches India and Nigeria, but
>   not Indiana. Note that this is not a global search, so where country
>   matches 'an' will not match 'Canada'.

In this case if I'm reading it correctly they mean dog will not match sometext/dogblabla it will; only match exactly. I'm not sure but my trial and error suggests my understanding is correct.

Is there a shorter way of writing `(.*)?dog(.*)?|(.*)?cat(.*)?|(.*)?fish(.*)?`

Comment: You might use `.*(dog|cat|fish).*`

Comment: Thanks. Would that be (.*)?(dog|cat|fish)(.*)? since there may or may not be preceding or trailing text?

Comment: No, `*` matches 0+ chars. You do not need the wrapping groups.

Comment: Oh. In that case many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `matches` in Google Charts requires a full string match, thus, `cat|dog|fish` won't work (see the example with `Canada`).

You may use lazy/greedy dot matching pattern before an alternation group with your search words, and then add the same construct after:

```
.*(dog|cat|fish).*
```

This will match:

- `.*` - any zero or more  (`*`) characters other than linebreak characters
- `(dog|cat|fish)` - either `dog`, `cat` or `fish`
- `.*` - any zero or more characters up to the end of the line.

If the input contains line break characters, you may either try replacing `.` with `[\s\S]` or add a `(?s)` at the start of the pattern.